# How to create a column with unique values conditioned on a condition in an other column?

Tags: r, for-loop, conditional-statements, lapply

I have a data.frame:

```
head(data)
    År                        Namn N_medlemmar
1 1938  Asea-personalens erk. Csk.        8796
2 1938 Bohuslän-Hallands erk. Csk.       73765
3 1938    Dala-Gäleborgs erk. Csk.       87053
4 1938     De dövstummas erk. Csk.         718
5 1938  Eskilstuna stads erk. Csk.       15657
6 1938       Gefle stads erk. Csk.        9316
```

I want to add a column `Code`with unique values conditioned on the `Name column` above. In example:

```
    År                        Name N_medlemmar  Code
1 1938   Asea-personalens erk. Csk.        8796  1
2 1938  Bohuslän-Hallands erk. Csk.       73765  2
3 1939  Bohuslän-Hallands erk. Csk.       12392  2
4 1940     Dala-Gäleborgs erk. Csk.       87053  3
5 1941      De dövstummas erk. Csk.         718  4
6 1942   Eskilstuna stads erk. Csk.       15657  5
7 1943   Eskilstuna stads erk. Csk.        9316  5
```

So the `Code` column is an unique value conditioned on the `Name` column above.

```
dput(data)
structure(list(År = c(1938L, 1938L, 1938L, 1938L, 1938L, 1938L
), Namn = c("Asea-personalens erk. Csk.", "Bohuslän-Hallands erk. Csk.", 
"Dala-Gäleborgs erk. Csk.", "De dövstummas erk. Csk.", "Eskilstuna stads erk. Csk.", 
"Gefle stads erk. Csk."), N_medlemmar = c(8796L, 73765L, 87053L, 
718L, 15657L, 9316L)), .Names = c("År", "Namn", "N_medlemmar"
), class = "data.frame", row.names = c(NA, 6L))
```

I tried `lapply` and `for` loop but didnt suceed... Any suggestions?
Best Regards!

Comment: I am struggling to see how your second data frame is derived from the first one.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

I think what you are asking for is

```
data$Code <- as.integer(as.factor(data$Namn))
```

Or just keep it as a factor.

Comment: @NPE Great! Thanks! Interesting solution! I accept your solution because it is handsome:) But does anyone have a solution about how to do it with `for` or `apply` family loops?

Comment: @user1665355 I have added as you requested below, two examples of things that *you should not do* in this situation. Either NPE's or my first solution are more than suited to this task. You will not achieve anything extra using `for` and `apply` family here.

Answer (score 2):

Or you can do it like this with match...

```
data$Code <- match( data$Namn , unique(data$Namn))
```

## Edit - regarding `for` and `apply` in this situation

Firstly may I ask why you are so keen to use a `for` or `apply` loop in this situation? It sounds a lot like you have an assignment that requires you to use a loop? If that is the case you should get extra credit for answering that you refuse to use one when vectorised methods are fully appropriate. If you *really, really* need to use a loop for some strange reason, one of many examples to achieve this could be:

```
data$Code <- rep( NA , nrow(data) )
for( i in 1:nrow(data) ){
  data$Code[i] <- match( data$Namn[i] , unique(data$Namn))
}
```

Do you see why this is inherently worse? Aside from being less efficient you have to do more typing and indexing to achieve the same result. In short, **DON'T DO IT!**

I also really recommend that you don't do (*in this situation*)...

```
data$Code <- unlist( lapply( data[,"Namn"] , function(x){ match( x , unique(data$Namn)) } ) )
```

*Use the vectors Luke.*

Comment: Yes, I see, but I just could not get my mind around it...Thanks!